# How to add data to a Arraylist from a diffrent class

Tags: java, arraylist, q

I have seen all the other questions to his topic but I didnt realy get much from it.Just started learning java so pls try to make  the explanation for me as simple as you can.

How do I add to my Arraylist "Fish" anything at all? I coudlnt even add something to it in the same class(line3 class question)... but I need to know how to add it in different a class.(I tried it in the end of class question 2 but it didnt work too)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class question {

    private String name;

    public ArrayList<String> Fish = new ArrayList<>();

    Fish.add(name); // <--- this for some reason doesnt work the point is red underlined as well as the ")"

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFish() {
        return Fish;
    }
}
```

second class

```
public class question2 {


    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // First try : question.getFish().add(nam1);
    // Second try   question.Fish.add(name1);
    //how do I add the name1 into my ArrayList "Fish".How can I transport my ArrayList from question1 to question2?
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: As for `Fish.add(name);` - you can't execute code outside of methods or an inializer block. Try `{ Fish.add(name); }` at the class level or better call it in the constructor.

Comment: Please also stick to the Java Coding Convention, (member) variables should start with a lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of research i found this: 
http://www.guj.com.br/t/chamar-instancia-em-outra-classe/349765/6

Check the awnser and run the code by debugging it, this way you can see step by step of what is going right or wrong.

Hope it helps you, if don't, later i can make a example for you.

PS: If your first class has just a constructor, you don't need to create the array there, you can just call the constructor on your second class and create the array there.

Comment: Not an answer. This belongs in a comment.

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment on his post my friend =)

Comment: Why dont you add code from that link modified according to question as answer instead to pointing an out source link

Comment: So get your reputation up to 50 and then comment on his post. We all did that. None of us are special in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

> Fish.add(name);

does not make any sense here. Such a statement must be inside a method. To get access to the field "Fish" (btw: please obey the Java naming conventions that strictly recommend fields to start with a lower case letter), you first need an instance of "question" (here again: classes start with an upper case letter).

> private String name;

what is that name for? It's a sibling of your ArrayList.

To add a fish to your ArrayList I would go with the following:

```
public void addFish(String name) {
    Fish.add(name);
}
```

Put that method inside your question class.

Regarding your second class: Both tries would work if they were inside a method and you had an instance of question in question2. I don't see the use of the question2 class here - but one possibility to add fish inside question2 would be:

```
public void addFish(question q, String name) {
    q.getFish().add(name);
}
```

I suggest you work through some nice java tutorials. It seems that you lack some basic understanding of OOP. I would start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Answer (score 0):

You might expecting this , I just updated your source code

Just copy paste, it should work :

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Question {

 private String name;

 public ArrayList<String> fish;

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public ArrayList<String> getFish() {
  return fish;
 }

 public void setFish(ArrayList<String> fish) {
  this.fish = fish;
 }
 
 public void addToFish(String name) {
  
  if(this.fish == null){
   this.fish = new ArrayList<>(); 
  }
  this.fish.add(name); 
 }
 
}
```

```js
public class Question2 {

 private String name;
 Question question = new Question(); 

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Question question = new Question(); 
  question.addToFish("question1");
  question.addToFish("question2");
  question.addToFish("question3");
  question.addToFish("question4");
  
  for(String fish : question.getFish()){
   System.out.println(fish);
  }
 }
  
}
```